# How Can I Optimize My MySQL Select Query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a database table that contains over 90,000 rows.

Each row contains a word that is either an adjective, adverb, noun, or verb (as indicated by a Type column).

I need to run a MySQL query that returns a small number (e.g. 3 - 10) of randomly chosen nouns where the length of the word is between two supplied numbers (e.g. 4 - 8).

The performance of the queries I've tried is not that great.

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `word` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `variations` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `free_writing_prompt` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `word_length` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `words`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `word_type` (`type`,`word`),
  ADD KEY `type` (`type`),
  ADD KEY `Word Length` (`word_length`);

ALTER TABLE `words`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The free_writing_prompt column is set to 0 or 1, 1 meaning it's a valid option for the query, and 0 meaning ignore it. At the moment, all of the nouns have this column set to 1, but the plan is to change many words to 0 because they are not nouns that should be returned.

Here's the row count, by Type:

Adjectives: 21,499
Adverbs: 4,475
Nouns: 58,670
Verbs: 8,978

This is the first query I tried:

```
SELECT  word
    FROM  words
    WHERE  type='n'
      AND  free_writing_prompt=1
      AND  CHAR_LENGTH(word)>=4
      AND  CHAR_LENGTH(word)<=8
    ORDER BY  RAND()
    LIMIT  3;
```

After this, I decided to add the word_length column, which was not originally part of the table definition, because using the CHAR_LENGTH function on all those rows seemed inefficient when I could pre-calculate and store that value instead.

I also thought it would be worthwhile building a Key index on the word_length column, but I'm not convinced it's really helped.

I then tried the following three queries, but they all still take about 16 seconds to run:

```
SELECT  word
    FROM  words
    WHERE  type='n'
      AND  free_writing_prompt=1
      AND  word_length>=4
      AND  word_length<=8
    ORDER BY  RAND()
    LIMIT  3;
SELECT  word
    FROM  words
    WHERE  type='n'
      AND  free_writing_prompt=1
      AND  word_length IN (
        SELECT  word_length
            FROM  words
            WHERE  word_length>=4
              AND  word_length<=8
                          )
    ORDER BY  RAND()
    LIMIT  3;
SELECT  word
    FROM  words
    WHERE  word_length IN (
        SELECT  word_length
            FROM  words
            WHERE  type='n'
              AND  free_writing_prompt=1
              AND  word_length>=4
              AND  word_length<=8
                          )
    ORDER BY  RAND()
    LIMIT  3;
```

I then tried this Union query, which was fractionally faster (but maybe not enough to be statistically significant):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT word FROM words WHERE type='n' AND free_writing_prompt=1 AND word_length=4
    UNION
    SELECT word FROM words WHERE type='n' AND free_writing_prompt=1 AND word_length=5
    UNION
    SELECT word FROM words WHERE type='n' AND free_writing_prompt=1 AND word_length=6
    UNION
    SELECT word FROM words WHERE type='n' AND free_writing_prompt=1 AND word_length=7
    UNION
    SELECT word FROM words WHERE type='n' AND free_writing_prompt=1 AND word_length=8
) a
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to optimize this query to improve the run time?

Comment: Having a COVERING INDEX might help, eg: `(free_writing_prompt, type, word_length[, word])`; if doing the order-by-take-then-join, should be able to keep `word` out with little impact (ie. join will only need to do 3 probes) - what does the query planner say is going on? Also, in general I think there are 'more favorable' solutions to 'ORDER BY RAND()'.

Comment: Note the ordering of the covering index is specific: both the `free_writing_prompt` and `type` are direct equality while `word_length` is a range (regardless of how it's written; should just use `AND word_length >= 4 AND word_length < 8` and _drop all the unions_ to cover the operation; doing SQL no favors by multiple direct equality here)

Comment: Thanks - I'd never head of a covering index before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Composite index**:

```
    WHERE  type='n'
      AND  free_writing_prompt=1
      AND  word_length>=4
      AND  word_length<=8
```

begs for

```
INDEX(type, free_writing_prompt,   -- in either order
      word_length)                 -- last
```

Even better, is to stretch it into a **covering index**:

```
INDEX(type, free_writing_prompt,   -- in either order
      word_length,                 -- last (for indexing purposes)
      word)                        -- to make "covering"
```

Your first `SELECT` will work well with this covering index.  Alas it won't be perfect since it will build a temp table of several thousand, sort it, then peel off 3 rows.